# How to get a DataGrid column name when the header is clicked, WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My data grid is using a different style so I can't use below code.Is there any other way of getting the column name in MVVM environment without changing existing style?
Please let me know.

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

The handler of click event i.e. columnHeader_Click will have sender as parameter that you can cast to DataGridColumnHeader and then access Content property

Comment: How do I use this in MVVM design? Do I need to tie Click Handler to a command?

Comment: In that case you can pass content as CommandParameter using command binding

Comment: Thanks. One more question.How do I create a command support for Event handler.Is there a way?

Comment: you need to convert event to command, I am not sure if you are using any MVVM framework like MVVMLight or something but you can also make your own commanding infrastructure. See, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code by doing a little modification on it.

```
     Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BaseOn="{StaticResource YourExistingStyle}"
```